# How to add a user account to a group (member of)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to add a windows account user to a group
I use this method:

```
public bool AddUserToGroup(PrincipalContext ctx, string userId, string groupName)
{
     try
    {
          GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName);
          group.Members.Add(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
          group.Save();
          return true;
    }
    catch
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

when I use this method with the following

```
PrincipalContext 
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Lab.net");
```

It works fine.

but when I use

```
PrincipalContext with username and password it have exception
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Lab.net","administrator","P@ssw0rd");
```

the exception is:

> *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Utils.GetDcName(String computerName, String domainName, String siteName, Int32 flags)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.LoadDomainInfo()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.get_DnsForestName()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADUtils.ArePrincipalsInSameForest(Principal p1, Principal p2)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Update(Principal p)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()*

I can create user with this PrincipalContext but I cant join a user to a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this:

```
public bool AddUserToGroup(PrincipalContext ctx, DirectoryEntry userId, string groupName)
{
    try
    {
        //GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName);
        //group.Members.Add(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
        //group.Save();
        GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName);
        if (groupPrincipal != null) {
            DirectoryEntry entry = (DirectoryEntry)groupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
            entry.Invoke("Add", new object[] { userId.Path.ToString() });
            userId.CommitChanges();
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```